# X11 Forwarding between two machines does *not* send launched app to client but launches on server

Tags: xorg, 20.04, x11-forwarding

I have been puzzled by this for some time, and keep wondering if I overlooked something simple.

Consider a simple case of two Linux machines. To keep it simple, have both be the same distro and version. We can call "laptop" and "server", but "local" and "remote" would work the same.

"Way back when" things where simple:

- (on laptop)  `ssh -X server` gets us onto server,

  - then calling `xterm &` make a new `xterm` appear on laptop
  - this is what we want: a *forwarded x11* application.

"These days" with the modern desktop environment

- (on laptop)  `ssh -X server` gets us onto server,

  - then calling `gnome-terminal &` make a new `terminal` appear *on server*
  - we fail to have a *forwarded x11* application.

I have a laptop (running 20.04) sitting next to my two-screen desktop/server (running 20.04) but for the life of me I can have the laptop request a server up be display on *its* screen (to give me a poor man's three-screen solution).

What am I missing?

*Edit:* Apparently I fell for a `gnome-terminal` and `chrome` feature and didn't check enough other apps.  Silly me.

Comment: This is likely specific to `gnome-terminal` - see for example [Run true multiple process instances of gnome-terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/run-true-multiple-process-instances-of-gnome-terminal)

Comment: Could be though I would swear I also tried old fashioned `xclock` (my usual test case) or other apps.  Lemme check. [ Checks. ] *Dang* You are correct.  Make it an answer and I accept.

Comment: Interesting.  `chrome`, which I had checked, does the same and "remains on server". `brave` come across, but doesn't draw, likely confused between gpu on server and none on desktop. `firefox` works, a little slowly though.